# How to remove first digit from a bigger number in python

Tags: python, loops

I have a task that requires me to work with loops and I can't figure out how to remove the first digit from a number a user inputs into a program (example: user inputs 9876). I need to get a number: 876 then work with it. Then again I need to remove the first digit and get: 76 until I get to the last number. The programming language is Python

Comment: You could convert to a string and then do `[1:]`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```py
number=int(str(number)[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> n = '9876'
>>> n[1:]
'876'
```

Convert the number to a string if its not alrrady and then just slice the string as above to exclude the first character.

Note that you have to assign this value to n to actually change the value of n; `n = n[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why I am adding this solution is because you mentioned in your description that you are `required` to `work with loops`. **I am not sure that string slicing is technically considered a loop, despite its iterator properties.** With the caveat of course that I consider slicing to be a more elegant solution, for the purpose of your assignment you can use this:

```
sequence = input('Input a number: ')

print(''.join([sequence[i] for i in range(1, len(sequence))]))
```

Hope this helped :) Cheers!